# Return INSERT output from a function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

When an `INSERT` is performed [its output is a command tag](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/sql-insert.html#AEN58365), e.g. `INSERT 0 1`.

I'd like to capture that same command tag from inside a function and return it.

I thought the `RETURNING` clause would help me, nevertheless it works similar to a `SELECT` query over the inserted rows, returning a table-like set. I do not want that. **What I want is to return the plain command tag** (i.e., the text "`INSERT 0 1`") that you get when performing an `INSERT`.

Here is a pseudo-code example of what I want to achieve (of course, `RETURN QUERY` does not work in this case since `INSERT` is a in a non-SETOF function

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_user_test (
    p_username text)
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY INSERT INTO users(username) values(p_username));
END $$;
```

How do I achieve what I need?

Comment: Just add `RETURNING *` to the end of the insert query. Your return type may need to change to `RETURNS SETOF users`. Or if you insist on returning text, you can use Gordon's answer and use `SELECT i.username FROM i;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not capture the message `INSERT 0 1` literally because that's not returned by the INSERT statement, but generated by the `psql` command line tool based on the *status* of the INSERT statement.

So if you want to see that message, you need to generate that yourself in the function (PL/pgSQL is not needed for this):

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_user_test (p_username text)
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE SQL
  AS $$
    with inserted as (
      INSERT INTO users(username) values(p_username))
      returning *
    )
    select concat('INSERT 0 ', count(*))
    from inserted;
  $$;
```

If you didn't mean to see the message `INSERT 0 1` then you can just return the username instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_user_test (p_username text)
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE SQL
  AS $$
      INSERT INTO users(username) values(p_username))
      returning username;
  $$;
```

Or the complete row including default values that was inserted:

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_user_test (p_username text)
    RETURNS setof users
    LANGUAGE SQL
  AS $$
      INSERT INTO users(username) values(p_username))
      returning *;
  $$;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a CTE with the `INSERT`:

```
WITH i as (
      INSERT INTO users (username)
          VALUES (p_username)
      RETURNING *
     )
SELECT i.*
FROM i;
```

Comment: Could you please provide a full example showing how to use it inside a function? I believe you answer is what I need but I'm unable to test it. I think I might be messing up with the `DECLARE` part of the function.

Answer (score 2):

Command tag "INSERT 0 1" is not directly available for plpgsql environment. You can get same information in different format via `GET DIAGNOSTICS` command.

```
DO $$
  DECLARE _oid oid; _rc bigint;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO foo VALUES(10);
  GET DIAGNOSTICS _oid = RESULT_OID; -- it is not supported on 12+
  GET DIAGNOSTICS _rc = ROW_COUNT;
  RAISE NOTICE 'INSERT % %', _oid, _rc;
END;
$$;
```

If you need more, then you should to use different language than PLpgSQL - special variant is C language, where all informations are available.